# Representation of data in core data

Tags: json, core-data

While debugging my app, it would be useful to get some kind of visual representation of the data that is stored in core data so I can better understand what is going on. But I am not aware of anyway that I can do this. JSON would be a great but obviously this can be tricky when there are loops in relationships. Does anyone know of any easy way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger)

It allow to explore data in chrome debugger :

[image]